# Minor Allele Frequency (MAF) higher than 0.5?

Tags: genetics, bioinformatics, statistics, allele

I have a set of data in PLINK format (*.bed, *.bim and *.fam files).  There are around 2000 individuals in my dataset.

I used PLINK to calculate allele frequencies in the population:

```
p-link --bfile data --freq
```

However, in the produced results file, many SNPs have a MAF over 0.5 (up to 0.82).  Would that not then make that the major allele frequency, as the other allele would have a frequency of 0.18?

Comment: can you add some more info about PLINK format and background info for the question so other users not as familiar can follow?

Comment: You should post an example section from your data file that reports MAF>0.5.